# How to find a compilation result's part file?

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, compilation, makefile

I am wondering how to find a file that should appear after compilation. There should be a file called `crt1.o` (I think in directory called `i686-linux-gnu`)
 but in my `/usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu` directory there are only: `liblouis.so.2` and `liblouis.so.2.2.0`

In directory where my files are I have run:

```
gcc -v add.o mul.o main.o -static -o main
```

As a result I recieved on the terminal:

`Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.4/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.4 --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.4 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.5 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/:/usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-static' '-o' 'main' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686'
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/collect2 --build-id -m elf_i386 --hash-style=gnu -static -o main -z relro /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/crtbeginT.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5 -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5 -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../.. -L/usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu add.o mul.o main.o --start-group -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lc --end-group /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/crtn.o
kris@ubuntu:~/Pobrane/cw4_libraries/ex2$ file main
main: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, not stripped`

Comment: `/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/crt1.o` is `/usr/lib/crt1.o`

Comment: But which path when I am in `/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5`?

Comment: Then it's `../../../../crt1.o` . Note that this file is an input to the linker, not an output file from your compilation. Also note that `/usr/lib/gcc/` or anything below that doesn't even need to exist. You can just do do e.g. `ls -l /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/crt1.o`

Comment: One other things. When I am on the top directory
`kris@ubuntu:/$ pwd
/
`
Can you provide some tips, please?

then I try and get:
`kris@ubuntu:/$ /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/crt1.o

bash: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/crt1.o: Permission denied`
And:
`chmod u+x /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/crt1.o`

Comment: You're trying to execute crt1.o, which isn't an executable. What are you really trying to do ?

Comment: I want to check by `readelf` that `crt1.o` really contains `_start` token

Comment: Then run `readelf -s /usr/lib/crt1.o`  (Or if you will, `readelf -s /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/crt1.o`)

Comment: Yes, it was it. Now my actions seems to be stupid event for me, but I am not familiar with linux, so thank you very much.